# Sort list of lists by multiple values in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I need to sort a list of lists, where each `entry` in the outer list is a list of three integers like this:

```
[[3,1,0],[1,2,3],[3,2,0],[3,1,1]]
```

The trick is that I need to sort it by `entry[0]`, and if there's a tie, then sort them by `entry[1]`, and if that's also a tie, sort by `entry[2]`, so the list above should be:

```
[[3,2,0],[3,1,1],[3,1,0],[1,2,3]]
```

I keep overthinking my loops and sort statements and I haven't been able to get a way to check the entries in order without rearranging my lists by those values instead of keeping the hierarchy.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

It's a default behaviour for comparing lists.

```
x = [[3,1,0],[1,2,3],[3,2,0],[3,1,1]]
x.sort(reverse = True)
print(x)
```